# I can't understand this strange JS Flow syntax

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm trying to remove some JS Flow typing syntax from an application, but I can't seem to refactor this certain line accurately. It's part of a class declaration:

```
declare class Error {
  static (message?:string): Error;
  static call(x: any): void;
  static captureStackTrace(x: any, x: any): void;
  name: string;
  message: string;
  stack: string;
}
```

The problematic line is `static (message?:string): Error;`.

**What is this line doing, and how can I rewrite it without Flow?**

It looks like a method but has no name.... Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a declaration of a factory function, just merged with class declaration.
So you can type check this: `const error = Error(message)`.

To be less confusing, it can be rewritten as `constructor (message?: string): Error`.
Then you'll need to use `new`: `const error = new Error(message)`.
Here is the example of both ways - [try flow](https://flow.org/try/#0CYUwxgNghgTiAEkoGdnwKIxgexvA3gFDzzIAuUZAlmPABQC2IqUA5iAPwBcpZMVAO1YBKHphwwANMUTYB5GAFcwZXPSYt2PAYoYAjEDFEYsuaQF9ChMHPLwA7jiEBGeAF4TEugBYATMOtbMgcnVl93eAEQe09cOgByP3iAwPlg7ABrVw9xOMTfZNS7TPCPKJjcmB9-IA)

So, without flow, you just need to write a function that returns Error object, and maybe check its first argument to be a `string` if not `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a pro in `flow`, but i'll try to answer your questions.

> What is this line doing

The method accepts an optional `string` variable named `message` and it returns an `Error` object.

> how can I rewrite it without Flow?

I think you can use `typeof` to check the type of the variable. You can find more information [here](https://toddmotto.com/understanding-javascript-types-and-reliable-type-checking/)

Comment: What would the name of the method be? It doesn't have a declared name like "call" or "captureStackTrace".

Answer (score 0):

For my understanding, this definition is to check the input type of primitive Error Object.

This kind of Flow semantic is called library definition which is used to define type check for 3rd party library. You could see the definition below.

[Flow defintion](https://flow.org/en/docs/libdefs/)

So what you need to do is create a customized Error function say myError and check the  first argument type as string. Then return Error Object.